# Remove whitespace with Cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I remove whitespace in a certain property value.
The amount of whitespace is different per node.

The values look like this:

```
"3220       BA"

"3223   NA"

"3231           MA"
```

Does something like `preg replace \s` exist in Cypher?

Comment: Is the intent to remove ALL internal whitespace (so the cleaned up version of the first would be '3220BA')? Or to condense it down to a single space (where the cleaned up version would be '3220 BA')?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
trim({original}), ltrim({original}),
 rtrim({original})
```

Trim all whitespace, or on left or right side

for Reference, Follow below link
http://neo4j.com/docs/pdf/neo4j-cypher-refcard-stable.pdf

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't remove the whitespace inside the text.

Answer (score 1):

Try [replace](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-replace):

```
replace( "3220       BA", " ", "" )
```

Comment: Look at [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#query-functions-string) to see what other string methods there are. Cypher has a lot of the basic tools for manipulating basic types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE (t:Test { prop: 'Tooo        many     whitespaces'}) 
MATCH (t:Test) SET t.prop = replace(t.prop, " ", "") RETURN t
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing non-breaking spaces instead of usual spaces, compare:

```
'ADP 5140'.split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))[3] // 160
```

and

```
'ADP 5140'.split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))[3] // 32
```

So I had to include in my Cypher the logic for removing both usual (ASCII code 32) and non-breaking (ASCII code 160) spaces:

```
return replace(replace('ADP 2119', ' ', ''), ' ', '')
```